# nginx force ssl exception

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx installed and SSL installed on main domain, which works fine. I have even parked 5-6 other domains with main domain. If I go to any of those domains, I get an SSL warning because I have forced HTTPS in nginx config using following config:

I have added following in `/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/APPNAME.d/redirect_to_https.nonssl_conf`

```
return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
```

And this correctly forces the HTTPS version to be served.

How could I implement some condition such as: **if domain is `main.example.com` then redirect to HTTPS version, otherwise show HTTP version**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any attempt at creating an `if` statement to return the https version of the site will result in a redirect loop (as your condition, `server_name` is not changing after the redirect, so will always match the condition and redirect again...).

With that said, what I would recommend would be to set up individual configuration files per virtual host/subdomain (I infer that from your current setup, you are using a single catch-all configuration - if this is not the case, please update your question accordingly)

You may also find the below a more elegant way of redirecting to https on the domain(s)/subdomain(s) you wish to be served always via https:

```
    if ( $scheme = http ){
            rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

For example you could create the following:

```
server {
  server_name nonssldomain.com anothernonssldomain.com;
  listen 80;
           }
```

in a file called non_ssl_sites.conf (or whatever you like), then another:

```
server {
  server_name ssldomain.com;
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  if ( $scheme = http ){
            rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }
           }
```

in a file called ssl_sites.conf (or again, whatever you prefer)

Comment: What i want to do is to check if domain is 'main.com' then force SSL.

Comment: Yes, so as above - you will need to create individual configuration files for each domain you want to serve from the server.

Comment: I have updated my answer above to reflect an example

Comment: Is there any way to use one configuration file like i already have and check for domain `if($domain == 'main.com') return 302 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: No, because as I have said above, you will find that this causes a redirect loop. You may use one configuration file but will need separate server segments as in my examples above.

Comment: BTW.. Can you tell me how to check for domain in nginx?

Comment: As above - the domain is checked against the `server_name` directive

Answer (score 3):

You should use a different server block for each "type" of domain you manage, so that you don't have to use if statements to test the $host variable.

```
# Domains to serve only via HTTPS
server {
  server_name domaintoredirect1.tld domaintoredirect2;
  listen 80;

  return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name domaintoredirect1.tld domaintoredirect2;
  listen 443 ssl;

  ...
}

# Domains to serve via both HTTP/HTTPS
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name otherdomain1.tld otherdomain2.tld;
}
```